# SAS batch download text files from the server

Tags: sas

There are a bunch of .txt files stored on the SAS server. I only want to download a subset of them. With a list of file names, how can I extract and batch download them?

Comment: What do you mean by 'download'?

Comment: download to my local PC from the server.

Comment: SAS Studio? EG? If EG look at the Copy Files task. Not sure with any other versions of SAS.

Comment: Wrong tool for the task.  If you want to download files from a server use an SFTP tool.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.